# C# DataGridView to Chart

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control with a Microsoft Access database loaded into it.  I need to take a selection of cells from the same column and graph those points on a chart.  I am not sure where to start, can anyone help me get started?

Comment: Can you post your code? What additional efforts do you made, what did you tried?

Comment: You can use a MSChart control. If you only want to use a selection of cells, the most direct way is to: Add add as many series as you need; then loop over the cells and add aDataPoints to a Series.Points collection using the values and maybe row/column indices of the cells as the X/Y values..

Comment: I am using an MSChart control. It's opening on a child form but I have no idea how to even start coding it so the DataGridView selection sets the points and such on the Chart control. That's why I haven't posted any code, I don't have any.

Comment: Removed some fluff